# python: get the most frequent value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries, having this shape:

```
xs = [ { 'date': 1 }, { 'date': 1 }, { 'date': 2 }, { 'date': 1 }, { 'date': 4 }]
```

I need to get the date that is mostly represented, the most popular date among all dictionaries

My approach would be:

1. sort the list by date
2. group by date
3. get the max() comparing groups length

example:

```
sorted_xs = sorted(xs, key=lambda x: x['date'])
ys = groupby(sorted_xs, lambda x: x['date'])
???
```

this doesn't work (and is ugly):

```
max(list(groupby(sorted_xs, lambda x: x['date'])), key=lambda (k, x):len(list(x)))
```

Do you know any method that is more simple and expressive in python?

Comment: Are there other keys in those dictionaries, or is the output `{'date': 1}` enough?

Comment: there are other keys but are irrelevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each date:

```
from collections import Counter

date_counts = Counter(d['date'] for d in xs)
most_common = {'date': date_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]}
```

I've assumed you wanted to get the output in the form of a dictionary again here, but you could just use `date_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]` directly if all you were interested in is that date value.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> xs = [{'date': 1}, {'date': 1}, {'date': 2}, {'date': 1}, {'date': 4}]
>>> date_counts = Counter(d['date'] for d in xs)
>>> {'date': date_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]}
{'date': 1}
```

Comment: Why did you include `[1]`? `[0]` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Joost: I need caffeine. Going to get some now.